# SQL Server 2008 Problem Find the Difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
ID   Name  Salary
-----------------
1    A     5000
2    B     2000
3    C     7000
4    D     6000
```

Now Problem is that we have to find the maximum salary and then find out the diff with other salaries.

In a Single Query.

Similarly we have to find with the 2nd and 3rd in the next query or in the similar query.

Comment: Is this some homework assignment? Not sure what the real world implications of this would be. Also, what kind of syntax are you looking for, pure SQL or Stored Procedure or another?

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm not sure this is homework or not, I don't want to just paste a query.

Here's some tips.

There is a MAX() function in sql that you could use to find the maximum value of a particular field.

You could then use that in other calculations, even in the same query.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
    SELECT x.id, x.name,
           x.salary,
           y.max_salary - x.salary AS diff
      FROM YOUR_TABLE x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(t.salary) AS max_salary
              FROM YOUR_TABLE t) y
```

To get the 2nd/3rd/etc highest salary, use:

```
    SELECT x.id, x.name,
           x.salary,
           y.max_salary - x.salary AS diff
      FROM YOUR_TABLE x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT u.max_salary 
              FROM (SELECT t.salary AS max_salary,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.salary DESC) AS rank
                      FROM YOUR_TABLE t) u
             WHERE u.rank = ?) y
```

Replace `?` with the position/rank you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 2):

When finding the difference between the max, use

```
SELECT ID, Name, Salary-(SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Salaries) AS SalaryDiff
FROM Salaries
```

To compare with the 2nd, 3rd etc.. highest salary (change `=2` to `=3`, `=4` etc. as needed.)

```
SELECT ID, Name, Salary-(SELECT Salary FROM (SELECT Distinct Salary from Salaries) 
      WHERE (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary))=2) AS SalaryDiff
FROM Salaries
```